# Determinant of coefficients as solution for system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I have problem that is essentially,
$$u=au+bv,$$
$$v=av+bu.$$
According to Kittel (Introduction to solid state physics Page 83) a condition for a solution is that "the determinant of the coefficients of $u$ and $v$ equals zero. That is,
$$det
\left(\begin{array}{cc} 
-1+a & b\\
b & -1+a
\end{array}\right)=0.
$$ 
Why is this true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transform your system into

$$\tag{1}\begin{cases}(-1+a)u+bv=0\\bu+(-1+a)v=0 \end{cases}$$

Let, us take the following notations:
$$D:=\det
\left(\begin{array}{cc} 
-1+a & b\\
b & -1+a
\end{array}\right), \ D_u:=\det
\left(\begin{array}{cc} 
0 & b\\
0 & -1+a
\end{array}\right), \ \ D_v:=\det
\left(\begin{array}{cc} 
-1+a & 0\\
b & 0
\end{array}\right).$$

Classical Cramer formulas [See (http://www3.ul.ie/~mlc/support/Loughborough%20website/chap8/8_1.pdf).]

$$u=\dfrac{D_u}{D}, v=\dfrac{D_v}{D}$$ evidently give $u=0, v=0$ as the unique solution to system (1).

We are faced to a so-called **homogeneous equation** with its "**trivial**" solution.

If you need non-trivial solutions, you will have to make Cramer formulas "crash" : a necessary (and in fact sufficient) condition to do that is to have determinant $D$ equal to zero.

In this case, automatically, you will have an **infinite number of solution to your system.**

Answer (score 0):

Because they two linear equations in which constants are $0$ there is always a trivial solution which is $(0,0)$. But for there to be non-trivial(solutions other than $(0,0)$) solution the equations must be multiples of each other and the way to check that is to see of the determinant is 0.